# Dismissible widget animation overlaps page push animation

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter 1.2.1 in the stable channel and have a list view that has items created using the [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) widget. Each item can be dragged to the right to delete, and left to edit.

In order to make sure the item is not removed when dragging left to edit I use the constructor parameter `confirmDismiss` which takes a callback function that determines whether the `Dismissible` should actually be dismissed.

In this `confirmDismiss` callback I check to see if the drag direction is to the left, if it is then I navigate to the `Edit` page in order to edit the item.

The problem is that when the navigation animation happens (to the `Edit` page) the animation to move the `Dismissable` item back into the list overlaps it, making it look buggy. This happens because my `confirmDismiss` callback stops the item from being permanently removed from the list (as it should) so there is an animation showing the item coming back into the list.

I would like it so that the animation moving the item back into the list happens underneath the animation navigating to the `Edit` page. Or at least make it so they don't overlap oddly like they are. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the constructor parameters of my `Dismissible` widget did the trick:

```
movementDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
```